# Implode error with $_POST values

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I'm try to use the `implode` function in `PHP`.

My array has this form:

```
Array (
    [color] => Yellow
    [size] => 122
    [country] => Array (
        [0] => Canada
        [1] => Brazil
        )
)
```

How to implode only the `country` datas to have something like that :

```
$countries = Canada,Brazil
```

I have tried:

```
$countries = implode(",", $_POST['country']);
echo $countries;
```

Actually `$_POST['country']` contains:

```
[country] => Array (
  [0] => Canada
  [1] => Brazil
)
```

Comment: So what is your current and expected output?

Comment: I wrote it : `$countries = Canada,Brazil`.

Comment: And you wrote exactly how to do it: `$countries = implode(",", $_POST['country']);`

Comment: So any idea why I do not have what I've wrote ?

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($_POST['country']);` Make sure Right click -> view source code and show us the output from there

Comment: My array is an array of array. That's why my solution does not work.

Comment: @Rizier123 : `string(43) "Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 99 ) "`.

Comment: @Thomas 1. You said it contains: `[country] => Array (
  [0] => Canada
  [1] => Brazil
)` 2. What you show now is a string not an array!